# Run script against replica set in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have replica set of 3 nodes and I want to run a cleanup script against it every end of day. What I would do if there was only single node would be a simple bash script:

```
~/mongo/bin/mongo host:port cleanupScript.js
```

But since I want to run the same script against replica-set I can't use this approach. I would need to somehow find which node is primary and run the script against that node.

So the question: Is there a way how to run the script against whole replica set and let the `mongo` process pick the primary node and execute on it?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this, but that is a great feature suggestion to 10gen for the mongo javascript shell.  The Java driver, at least, lets you specify the hosts in the replset as a collection: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.9.0/com/mongodb/Mongo.html Mongo(java.util.List seeds, com.mongodb.MongoOptions options) .  For this one feature alone I've given up on the javascript shell for my maintenance tasks and script it all through Groovy with the Java Driver.

Comment: the shell supports this already, at least as far back as 2.0 branch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The mongo shell can connect directly to a replica set - this works with 2.4 (current), 2.2 (previous) and 2.0 (the version before that).

Assuming you have a replica set called `myrs` and your hosts are `host1:27017` and `host2:27017`, use the following syntax:

`mongo --host myrs/host1:27017,host2:27017`

The shell will figure out the rest, including connecting to the primary and if the primary steps down or goes away it will reconnect to the new primary once it's elected.

Comment: Thanks @asya-kamsky - IHMO this is the best answer to this question. This one liner works for me from any host, primary or secondary ... `mongo -host myReplicaset/myServer1 myDb --eval "db.myCollection.remove( {<myQuery>} )"`

Comment: thanks. it uses the server name(s) as seeds to find out the full topology of the replica set, that's why you can give it any node in a replica set that's up and responding.

Comment: Where did you get the information on mongo host specification? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @re5et I don't remember as this was a while ago. you can see this mentioned in a few places - one is Jira ticket to make shell compatible with other drivers. Of course the other is the source code.

Answer (score 3):

I normally set priority for a node in replicaset. This gives me freedom to chose which node should get read and write load.

In your  case, I think, if you set priority for the nodes then you can always run your script against the highest priority node as that node will be primary almost all the time.

Setting priority is quite simple and straight forward. You can check this link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/

I hope this will solve your problem.

OKAY.... Probably this is what you need..

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PRIMARY=`~/mongo/bin/mongo localhost:27017 --eval "printjson(rs.isMaster())" | grep "primary" | cut -d"\"" -f4`

echo "$PRIMARY"

~/mongo/bin/mongo "$PRIMARY" cleanupScript.js
```

Run this on any node and it will give you the "server:port" of the primary. Give full path to the mongo executable.. just to avoid errors.

PS: the whole command is in the backticks. Somehow those are not visible so thought of telling you.

Comment: Yes, I know about the priorities. The problem is: "almost" all the time. What about if the node with highest priority dies? I need a 100% reliable way to run the script so I can't rely on priorities.

Comment: Yep, I'll probably end up parsing the output and connecting to primary, thanks +1

Comment: Works perfectly. I modified mine slightly as I needed just the port number: add '|cut -d":" -f2' to the end of the command to get the port #

Comment: or you can just let the mongo shell do the work and give it replSet name to connect to.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the 'mongo' shell does not support making connections to a replica set: only to individual nodes.  You have two choices if you want to do this:

- Use a different language, which supports making a connection to a replica set.  (PHP, Python, Perl, Java and Ruby all support this.)
- Have a driver script that runs an 'rs.status()' command, parses the output of that command, and determines the current primary.  If it's not the node you've connected to, then re-connect to the correct primary node

I wish I had a better answer for you.

Comment: Yep, I thought the pure shell would be nice solution but since it doesn't support it ... Thanks for the tips +1

Comment: I ended up running via the Java driver ... seems to be clean solution. If I have parsed the rs.status() there is still non-0 possibility of the primary getting changed after the parse and before I run the script :)

Comment: If you're worried about that small of a window, make sure that you've written your Java code to properly handle the MongoException that will be thrown if there is a primary fail-over while the script is running.

Comment: see my answer - you can do it with the shell directly.

Answer (score 0):

For more recent versions of mongo (I'm using 4.4.4), you can specify the replica set name, and only a single host (any one), and mongo will figure it out and drop you into a shell on the PRIMARY:

```
mongo --host my_repl_name/any_node_host:port --eval "..."
```

I found this to be really helpful when, for example, you're running in a cloud across several zones with duplicate local host names.

I tested this running mongo v4.4.4.